# How to detect WHICH folders OneDrive for Business are syncing

Tags: onedrive

I am trying to figure out exactly which folders are being synced when using OneDrive for Business.

When trying to solve sync issues I used the below fix and now it seems that the folders I used to sync are no longer synced - is that correct?

Before I tried to fix the sync issue I stopped the following services:

```
GROOVE.EXE
integratedoffice.exe
MSOIDSVC.EXE
MSOIDSVCM.EXE 
MSOSYNC.EXE
```

Then I deleted cachefiles:

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\Spw
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\15.0\OfficeFileCache
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look up

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Internet\LocalSyncClientDiskLocation`

in the registry. This should show you all of the local folders that are syncing to SharePont / OneDriveForBusiness.

e.g.

```
reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Internet /v LocalSyncClientDiskLocation`
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix-up @alanjmcf

Answer (score 0):

The URLS are in
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\SyncEngines\Providers\OneDrive

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).