# Microsoft Office Document shows Sharepoint URL instead of Local

Tags: c#, sharepoint, office-interop, onedrive

Situation: OneDrive for Business syncs files from Sharepoint Site Document Library to local directory:

```
C:\Users\users\Sharepoint\Library\Test.pttx
```

However with PowerPoint InterOp the:

```
presentation.Path
```

Is:

```
https://company.sharepoint.com/Library/Shared%20Documents/
```

Which is the correct path for Sharepoint.

How can I access the local directory?

Update: I found a [similar question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1331519b-1dd1-4aa0-8f4f-0453e1647f57/how-to-get-physical-path-instead-of-url-onedrive?forum=officegeneral) on MSDN but no answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26998808), the synced folders can be looked up in this multi-string registry value:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common
\Internet\LocalSyncClientDiskLocation`

Given that your local path and SharePoint URL look like

`C:\Users\User\SharePoint\Library - Documents\Folder\SubFolder\Document.pptx` and
`https://***.sharepoint.com/Library/Shared%20Documents/Folder/SubFolder/Document.pptx`,

you could try extracting the local part `Folder/SubFolder/Document.pptx` from the URL, add it to the local folder paths retrieved from the registry value and check for file existence.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you want a way in Powerpoint (VSTO) to get the local path of the Sync'd directory? A method in the Powerpoint Object Model like **presentation.GetLocalPath()**?

I dont know why (in the [MSDN link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1331519b-1dd1-4aa0-8f4f-0453e1647f57/how-to-get-physical-path-instead-of-url-onedrive?forum=officegeneral) in your question) the MSFT CSG engineer said  that it was impossible.

> Sorry for the mistake, after the further investigation, it is
>   impossble.   For the Word Application, the file is stored on the
>   OneDrive, and the "Offline" is       cache mode for OneDrive, it is
>   transparent to Word Application (Word Application only   know it is a
>   document on OneDrive), so when you check the location of the opened
>   document, the location is "http:/d.docs.live.net/xxxx/xx.docx" rather
>   than "C:\XXX\XXX".

This article shows you how you can [Change the location where you sync SharePoint libraries on your computer](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-location-where-you-sync-SharePoint-libraries-on-your-computer-ca8a88f6-bc4f-4ec2-a460-864c4e9b2be0?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). Obviously there isn't a method in the Powerpoint Interop Library but its definitely possible.

1) My first thought was to see if the  OneDrive for Business sync app wizard saves any registry key or anything like that (using ProcessMonitor) but it probably stores the local directory in the cloud.

2) My second thought is a bit outside the box, just put a text file in https://company.sharepoint.com/Library/Shared%20Documents/LocalDrivePath.txt, then create an Extension method called presentation.GetLocalPath() and use the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring(v=vs.110).aspx) class to download the string.

[image]

Pseudo code:

```
public string GetLocalPath(this Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation presentation)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string localPath = client.DownloadString(presentation.Path + "LocalDrivePath.txt");

    //Some good old protective programming to quickly identify the problem if the file doesn't exist
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(localPath)) throw new Exception("Issue: LocalDrivePath.txt not found in " + presentation.Path + Environment.Newline + "Please add the file for this Office Documents' sync'd (offline) local folder to be identified.");

    return localPath;
}
```

Call it like so:

```
presentation.GetLocalPath();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into this. For 1) so no registry key was written and we don't know where it stores the path right? For 2) do I understand correctly that I have to know the location at least once to store it in the .text ? I mean if I knew the location then I could store it anywhere, no? Another idea I had was to search for the file locally and path part of the path.

Comment: That 3rd method (search for the file) seems like a good resort if the folder should ever change using method 2. You're right when you find the directory you could store it anywhere, a txt file in SharePoint was the easiest to demonstrate.